# Bootstrap modal appearing when I click the Back Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a webform using C# ASP .NET 4.5.

My modal is working great for the most part.  I have a page called CustomerLookup.aspx that uses the bootstrap modal.  But when I close the modal, navigate to my site's home page, and then click the back button to go back to my CustomerLookup.aspx page - the modal appears.

I don't know if it makes a difference, but these two pages use a different MasterPage.

I am using Bootstrap 3.0.0

Here is the JS code in my Site.Master

```
function openModal() {            
        $('#uxModal').modal('show');
    }
```

Here is my code-behind on the button click event to pop up my modal:

```
protected void uxTestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
    }
```

Comment: Please share the code that shows the modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the same issue when I used an HTML button control - only with the asp:Button server control.  I'm just going to get away from server controls altogether - like I'm supposed to.